OCSP Stamping and Server Side Status check when OCSP server is NOT reachable causing 5 seconds delay for TLS handshake
We wanted to use the OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol) feature with the TLS handshake, aka OCSP stapling. As part of that, we turned it on at the JDK level by passing the flag "-Djdk.tls.server.enableStatusRequestExtension=true".  As a result, the TLS handshake took more than 5 seconds due to the unreachable (firewall)  OCSP server from the server.  Based on this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ocsp.html, we can reduce this by using '-Djdk.tls.stapling.responseTimeout=1000'
Is there any way to have JDK cache ERROR response and try only after 'jdk.tls.stapling.cacheLifetime=3600' (1 hr) again?  The Observation is that each TLS handshake is paying the penalty of 5 seconds when the OCSP server is not reachable because the response is NOT found in the Cache.
Any way to avoid this or cache an ERROR response?  is there any way to customize this behavior OCSP caching?
Thanks
